# Android Error:(65) No resource identifier found for attribute 'marginBottom' and 'marginTop' in package 'android'

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="gazete.alperenadatepe.test.MainActivity" >


<!--- Toolbar Layout -->
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" >

    <!-- Toolbar -->
    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>



<!-- Fragments Layout -->
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <!-- home page stock values layout -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/stock_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <!-- Title -->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Test Title Text"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="60dp" />

        <!-- Dollar Value -->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/dollar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Test Dollar Text"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:marginTop="16dp"
            android:marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="104dp" />

        <!-- Dollar Image -->
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/dollarImage"
            android:layout_width="36dp"
            android:layout_height="36dp"
            android:src="#d01107"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:marginTop="16dp"
            android:marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="94dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp" />

        <!-- Gold Value -->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/gold"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Test Gold Text"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:marginTop="16dp"
            android:marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="170dp" />

        <!-- Gold Image -->
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/goldImage"
            android:layout_width="36dp"
            android:layout_height="36dp"
            android:src="#900144"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:marginTop="16dp"
            android:marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="160dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp" />

        <!-- Euro Value -->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/euro"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Test Euro Text"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:marginTop="16dp"
            android:marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="230dp" />

        <!-- Euro Image -->
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/euroImage"
            android:layout_width="36dp"
            android:layout_height="36dp"
            android:src="#e55770"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:marginTop="16dp"
            android:marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="220dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp" />

        <!-- Stock Value -->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/stock"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Test Stock Text"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:marginTop="16dp"
            android:marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="302dp" />

        <!-- Stock Image -->
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/stockImage"
            android:layout_width="36dp"
            android:layout_height="36dp"
            android:src="#510622"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:marginTop="16dp"
            android:marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="292dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp" />

        <!-- Analog Clock -->
        <AnalogClock
            android:layout_width="128dp"
            android:layout_height="128dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="51dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>

<!-- Navigation Drawer -->
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="304dp"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:itemTextColor="#123456"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_drawer_header"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation_drawer_menu" >

</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
```

Hi!.What is the problem with this code. After i add this code to the xml. I get **Error:(65) No resource identifier found for attribute 'marginBottom' and 'marginTop' in package 'android'**  Please Help Me..

Comment: It's `layout_marginBottom`, and `layout_marginTop`. You're missing the `layout_` on both.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why would Eclipse tell me there is no attribute “margin” for a LinearLayout?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17386359/why-would-eclipse-tell-me-there-is-no-attribute-margin-for-a-linearlayout)

Comment: Oh men you are awesome !... Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Yeah it could be possible duplicate but i couldnt realized that is marginTop not layout_marginTop so i opened new. thanks again!..

Comment: Yeah, no worries. That's just so we can close your question as answered. Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

Replace `android:marginTop` with `android:layout_marginTop`
and `android:marginBottom` with `android:layout_marginBottom`

Hope it helps